# Examples of when Newton's Method will fail?

Tags: approximation, newton-raphson

I'm currently working on Newton's Method, and my instructor gave four instances where Newton's Method will fail.

(A) Newton's method converges to another solutions x=b such that f(b)=0 instead of converging to the desired solution x=a.

(B) Newton's method eventually gets into the never ending cycle, bouncing between the same two approximations $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$.

(C) Eventually, each next approximation $x_{i+1}$  falls further from desired solution $x_a$ than the previous approximation $x_i$  determined by the Newton's method.

(D) Newton's method is not able to find the next approximation $x_{i+1}$  because f'($x_i$)=0 or f'($x_i$) Does Not Exist.

However, there aren't any examples of when this happens. Would anyone be willing to provide examples of these instances?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Example for Case (A):  $$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2} - \frac{1}{2},$$ which has roots at $x \in \{-1,1\}$.  The initial choice $x_0 = 2$ converges to the negative root.

Example for Case (B):  $$f(x) = \begin{cases}\sqrt{x}, & x \ge 0 \\ -\sqrt{-x}, & x < 0 \end{cases}$$ has the peculiar property that for **any** initial guess $x_0 \ne 0$, the orbit is trapped in a cycle of period $2$, with $x_k = -x_{k-1}$.  This is quite easy to prove and is left as an exercise for the reader.

Example for Case (C):  $$f(x) = x^{1/3}.$$  The Newton's method recursion has no fixed point except for the initial guess $x_0 = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

For $A$, suppose you have a function with multiple zeros like $f(x) = \sin x$. Depending on your starting point, you will see that you could converge to any of the roots ($x = n\pi$), even if you want it to converge to a particular $x = \pi$ for example - say you start with $x_0 = 7\pi / 4$

For $B$, imagine a function whose gradient is very sharp - almost vertical. Then there is a chance that the tangent will cut at a point beyond the root, and then when you repeat at the new point, it will come back to the original point (Something like $f(x) = \arctan x$ at $x = 0$)

For $C$, if your starting point is too close to a stationary point, the next point is very far away, and will keep pushing the point further and further from the root

Comment: When you say too close to a stationary point, does that mean too close to another root?

Comment: No, a point where $f'(x) = 0$

Comment: Sorry, I added in another instance that I forgot to put in. Would you mind looking at it?

Comment: $f(x) = x^2 +1$ :)

Answer (score 3):

(A) $f(x) = x^2-1$ and start near $x=-1$ when you 'want' $x=1$.

(B) $f(x) = \sqrt{1+x^2}$ and start at $x=1$.

(C) $f(x) = \arctan x$ and $x_0>2$ (needs a little work to show that the Newton iteration diverges).

(D) $f(x) = x^3-1$ with $x_0 = 0$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @LutzLehmann The first example was missing a $-1$, the second was to illustrate the Newton iteration bouncing between the same two approximations.